# Mysql - Create a new row in table for each distinct value in a column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-insert

I have searched but not quite found what I am looking for.  I need to create a new entry in a table for each existing entry with a unique id.
For example - my table is like this.

```
 id   userid    action
 ---  --------  ----------
 1    55        Red
 2    55        Blue
 3    56        Red
 4    56        Blue
```

For each unique Userid, I need to add another entry - for example

```
     id   userid    action
     ---  --------  ----------
     1    55        Red
     2    55        Blue
     3    56        Red
     4    56        Blue 
     5    55        Green
     6    56        Green
```

Is this possible??

Comment: I think so. check this out: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-into-select/. My understanding is that you are inserting into a subquery version of itself.

Comment: *Why* exactly do you need to do this? It sounds like you'd just be creating duplicates. Can you not simply reference the existing values? Just worried you may be asking about an [**XY problem**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378), which you may be approaching the [**wrong way**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676)

Comment: Because these are actually custom profile fields and I need to autofill a new profile field that was just created.  So, for each user, I need to have a database entry showing the new field with a value so that I can pull it in reports.  I am not in control of the way the tables are laid out (I would just create a new column in the user profile table) but this is the way that Moodle allows you to create new custom fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `insert ... select` syntax to generate a new record for each distinct `userid`:

```
insert into mytable(userid, action)
select distinct userid, 'Green' from mytable
```